# How to discover that a DataColumn's underlying datatype is xml

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datatable, sqldataadapter

I have a SQL Server data table that has an xml column. I run a select query using `DataTable` (`Fill` method of the `SqlDataAdapter` class). After execution, the type of the column is `string`.

I am wondering how I could determine the actual SQL Server datatype (in this case `xml`) from the `DataTable` materialized by the `Fill` method.

I cannot use `SqlDataReader` (which has `GetSchemaTable` method that returns the SQL Server datatype information) - I have to use `SqlDataAdapter/DataTable`. Doing something like:

```
DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(table);
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

is also not helpful since it also does not seem to contain the SQL Server datatype information.

Comment: You could always "inspect" the column's datatype in the SQL Server catalog views by executing something like this: `SELECT user_type_id
FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Person.Person')`. If that value is `241` - it's a column of SQL Server datatype `XML` (those types are defined in `sys.types`)

Comment: That would mean I have to issue another query. Any way to not go to sql but rely on the obtained data table? Additionally, I could be executing a stored proc that returns data and not know apriori that table/schema it belongs to

Answer (score 5):

There is a property on the `SqlDataAdapter` called `ReturnProviderSpecificTypes` and if you set this true, then `GetSchemaTable()` should tell you the column is `typeof(SqlXml)` rather than `typeof(string)`